# cors-js in an ExpressJs app is blocking a request that should go through

Tags: express, cors, fetch

I believe I am setting up my express app's [CORS](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) settings correctly, but my request still fails.

Express Cors setup:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["localhost"]
  })
); 
app.options("*", cors()); // include before other routes
```

Also tried

```
app.use(
  cors()
); 
app.options("*", cors()); // include before other routes
```

Request:

```
            fetch(`localhost:5000/charge`, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: (
                    JSON.stringify({
                        stripeToken: token.id,
                        chargeAmount: Math.round(100 * this.state.donationAmount) // Needs to be an integer in cents
                    })
                )
            })
                .then(res => {
                    return res.text();
                })
                .then(txt => {
                    console.log(txt);
                })
```

Browser Error:

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/charge' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Any idea what is failing here? I need the respones so `no-cors` won't work for me.

Comment: Try adding `.catch()` for fetch req and see what error info u get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin was just a string, not a RegEx. RegEx must be defined like this: `origin: [/.*localhost.*/]`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the full url of the frontend and also add methods like this:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:5000'],
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    credentials: true // enable set cookie
}));
```